# Delete or comment a line in multiple feature files in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, behat, gitlab-ci-runner, gherkin

I want to comment out a single line of Gherkin code in gitlab across 100+ feature files. I can do it manually if its for ~10 but we are talking about 100+ here.

I use gitlab, behat and Gherkin.

I have access to server. So, looking for some back end commands to comment the single line without even looking at the front end.

Comment: The end result would be to remove it from the scenarios or just to not execute it for a period of time?

Comment: Removing it forever.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's possible that theres a CLI way to accomplish this, but I think your IDE is likely the best suited for this job. If it were me, I would use `Replace in Path` in Phpstorm - other IDE's should have similar functionality. Note most IDE's should be able to connect to a remote server as an FTP if not using VCS.